# odoo 12 psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

## Impacted versions:

odoo 12 , postgresql 10

## Steps to reproduce:

docker containers
odoo container was working pretty fine for months, but after trying to upgrade odoo version..
I got the following error..

> > psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address

- Postgresql container port:5432
- Both containers [odoo & Postgresql] joined same network

## Current behavior:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

## LOG :

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 171, in **init** , self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 540, in _locked , return fun(self, *args, **kwargs) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 608, in borrow , **connection_info) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 130, in connect , conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) ,psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known - - - ,2019-09-15 15:01:26,057 1 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating shutdown ,2019-09-15 15:01:26,058 1 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown. ,2019-09-15 15:01:30,959 1 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0-20190816 ,2019-09-15 15:01:30,960 1 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf ,2019-09-15 15:01:30,960 1 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/12.0', '/mnt/extra-addons', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons'] ,2019-09-15 15:01:30,961 1 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@db:5432 ,2019-09-15 15:01:31,104 1 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf ,2019-09-15 15:01:31,265 1 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 574638c2fd44:8069 ,2019-09-15 15:01:40,043 1 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files ,2019-09-15 15:01:40,072 1 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed ,2019-09-15 15:01:40,079 1 INFO ? werkzeug: - - [15/Sep/2019 15:01:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.031 ,2019-09-15 15:01:40,086 1 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request: , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in **call** , return self.dispatch(environ, start_response) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in **call** , return self.app(environ, start_wrapped) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in **call** , return self.app(environ, start_response) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1453, in dispatch , self.setup_db(httprequest) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1376, in setup_db , httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1537, in db_monodb , dbs = db_list(True, httprequest) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1504, in db_list , dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/db.py", line 375, in list_dbs , with closing(db.cursor()) as cr: , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 657, in cursor , return Cursor(self.**pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 171, in __init** , self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 540, in _locked , return fun(self, *args, **kwargs) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 608, in borrow , **connection_info) , File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 130, in connect , conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) ,psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known - - -
>   ''''

Comment: That seems to be a DNS problem. To confirm, go to your docker instance bash shell and run: `host <database server name>` It shoud return the same error message.

Comment: Hello Adan,     
result >> <database server name> has address 172.18.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

- @ odoo.conf I changed `db_host = my_database_server_ip` previous it was `db_host = db`
- restart container

It back to work :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the `--link` option for docker command.

you first should have the `postgresql` container running:

`$ docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db postgres:10`

as you can see, the container name is `db`.

and then you should have the `odoo` instance up and running:

`$ docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo`

as you can see here the `--link` option is telling the `odoo` container to map all requests to `db` host to the container named `db`

Comment: Hello Ahmed,

Thank you for the response.  The two containers **already linked**, and it was running fine for months:  
<br/>
`docker network create --driver bridge ov-nw`    
`sudo docker run -v ov-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --network ov-nw --name db-ov postgres:10`  

`sudo docker run -v odoo_addons:/mnt/extra-addons -v ov_data:/var/lib/odoo -p 8008:8069 --network ov-nw --name odoo-ov --link db-ov:db -t odoo:latest`      
but suddenly -I guess after odoo image updated- the error appear
Any ideas?